# Can I modify contract?

Tags: erc-20

I have issued a contract, but it doesn't contain subtract totalsupply logic, I want to modify the original contract, how can I do that with same contract address?

Does some one know? Please help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

No that is not possible. Contract once deployed cannot be modified. You need to deploy new contract again.

Comment: thanks to reply, the old contract issued tokens, it is a trouble to issue a new contract.